# Example of git API call that specifies pagination with access token included

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have this:

```
curl https://api.github.com/orgs/company/repos?access_token=<token>
```

It only returns the first 30 results, which I've read is the default. How would I modify this to set the pagination to include the rest of the results?

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that I was not using quotes when trying to add the `page=` to the call. So in case anyone else is as dense as I can be, the curl command would look like this:

```sh
curl -i 'https://api.github.com/orgs/company/repos?access_token=<token>&page=2'
```

and so on for the number of pages you have.

Comment: Holy Crap...I've spent IDK how long cursing iTerm, the OS and Github...tried learning Ruby to address this with Octokit (nightmare) and all what was missing was a stupid quote?  ARRRRRGGHHH.  Thanks tho, you saved me the shame of (gasp) asking for help!